# Build off-screen view from view hierarchy

Tags: macos, printing, darkmode

The apple doc states:

> **Printing Views**
>
> When you print an `NSView` through an `NSPrintOperation, its appearance now gets temporarily replaced by the aqua appearance during rendering. This is done to avoid printing with an inherited dark appearance. The` NSView instance’s own appearance property—if it’s
> set—is left unaltered, so it remains possible to print views with a
> nonstandard appearance, if desired.
>
> **Use separate, off-screen views to
> print the contents of on-screen windows**. To avoid altering the
> contents of on-screen windows, the darkAqua appearance isn’t replaced
> when printing views that are simultaneously hosted in a window.

I have a fairly complex NSView hierarchy, which is shown on screen in a window, and I need to print. So it seems I am in this exact case.
(and indeed, I see colour problems when printing in dark mode, when all is fine in light mode).

How do I replicate my NSView hierarchy in an offscreen NSView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this:

```swift
public protocol Printable {
    
    func printView() -> NSView
}


extension NSView: Printable {
    
    @objc
    open func printView() -> NSView {
        let view = NSView(frame: self.frame)
        for subView in self.subviews {
            let printableSubView = subView.printView()
            view.addSubview(printableSubView)
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

So each view is responsible for returning a `printView` of itself that is printable. For example, when I have a view that shows an image, it would just return an NSImageView (with the right image, of the right size etc...).

Some views can just return an empty `NSView` if they don't need to be printed (e.g. screen decoration views). That's what the default extension implemntation does.

And at document level, I have something loke this:

```swift
    override func printOperation(withSettings printSettings: [NSPrintInfo.AttributeKey : Any]) throws -> NSPrintOperation {
        let printView   = _myView.printView()
        let printInfo   = NSPrintInfo(dictionary: printSettings)
        printInfo.horizontalPagination  = .automatic
        printInfo.verticalPagination    = .automatic
        return NSPrintOperation(view: printView, printInfo: printInfo)
    }
```

Works like a charm, whatever the Appearance mode.